# Scrollview in android app won't scroll

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a ScrollView, and I've made sure that it only has one child, and that it's set to `match_parent` like in previous posts, but I still can't get it to scroll. Can anyone help me out?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            tools:context="com.thevisitapp.visitapp.PlacesActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/summaryLabel"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:text="summary"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/summary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/summaryLabel"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                tools:text="actual summary"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contactsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/contactsLabel"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:text="contact"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/phoneLayout"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/phoneImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_phone"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        tools:text="phoneNumber"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/emailImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_email"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        tools:text="email"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mediaLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/contactsLayout"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/media"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Media"
                        android:background="@color/gray"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/facebook"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/twitter"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_twitter"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_above="@+id/contactsLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Change the outermost `LinearLayout`'s `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: The scrollview only scrolls if its height is bigger than the parent height. Is that the case in your layout?

Comment: @MikeM made the change, but still no luck.

Comment: and @oberflansch yes it is bigger than the parent height.

Comment: Oh, I bet it doesn't like your nested MapFragment. See if it'll scroll if you remove that temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use wrap content in sub views.

2.Try to add a parent view (Linear or relative) and then add a child scroll view .This gives you more control over the entire view

Comment: I made edited my code so that it is wrapped by a `RelativeLayout` and added nothing besides that. However, it still doesn't work. I also tried changing all the subviews to `wrap_content`

Comment: The fragment that u r using might be consuming the scroll gesture try commenting it and test.

Comment: That did it. So I'm guessing my temporary solution will be to just make the content underneath the fragment scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout should be wrap_content instead of match_parent.